# What Python Framework/database should I use for my webapp

Tags: javascript, python, database, web-applications, web-frameworks

I am working on building a webapp. I have been learning Python on my own for a few months but I need help figuring out HOW to proceed with building the app, specifically which web framework/database to use.

As I'm fairly new to this, I may not be using the correct terms, and
I'm sure many of these things may be obvious, but this is a basic list
of what I need the framework to be able to do:

- I need to have a database, I'm not sure how large, the data is coming from an API that API returns JSON which I parse in python using Simple JSON, so I think it's just string dictionaries. For the API data I'd prefer to have one large database with with every key/value from the dictionary being a column/value in the database, as this seems like it would be the easiest to query - please let me know if this is an incorrect assumption.
- In the front end of the webapp, which I've been told will need to
  be written in Javascript, users will query the datastore using various
  different parameters (e.g.show me the last 10 posts from blogs
  X,Y, and Z, show me topics that were posted to by blog A and blog B.)
- The framework should track user activity and save the data to use
  it for future recommendations. Multiple users will be making queries at the
  same time, and the framework should be saving their activity while
  returning the data they requested.
- The webapp should be scalable, so it can handle the requests in the
  event that the app gets a surge in traffic/users etc. for any reason. This is currently a small project but in the case that more people want to use it I'd like to have that be an option without having to re-program it from scratch.
- Lastly, as I'm fairly new to programming, all things equal, or
  nearly equal I would much prefer a framework that is easy to use.

Comment: There's really no single answer here... its more of a question that belongs on IRC.

Answer (score 3):

Go with Django all the way https://www.djangoproject.com/

Answer (score 0):

There are many, many, many ways to do what you seem to want to do.

I've been working on a home project that uses tornado.web (easy REST api), mongodb (storage, works espectially well with JSON documents), and nginx (load balancing for surges in requests).

For the front-end, I'm using nginx to serve static web content... which is comprised of a Backbone.js application for various CRUD operations.

But that's just how I did it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest Google App Engine. It is free to start, very easy to use with lots of sample code. It is PAAS and see this short management introduction: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ckVyxODiTIo